# Cross Application Navigation (LaunchPad)

Tags: sapui5

There is an application (SplitView) at the level of LaunchPad, inside it, in details, another application opens. How do I go back a step (by clicking on the "Back" button) at the opened application and return to the previous detail screen? There is an address line at the start of the application, and the address bar after opening inside another application:

before:

> https://sap-gwd.m.com:1000/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/ui2/ushell/shells/abap/FioriLaunchpad.html#WorkflowTask-displayInbox?Origin=ECDCLNET210%252CTS90000001&scenarioId=PAYMENT&showAdditionalAttributes=true&/detail/ECDCLNET210/000004883109/TaskCollection(SAP__Origin='ECDCLNET210',InstanceID='000004883109')

after:

> https://sap-gwd.m.com:1000/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/ui2/ushell/shells/abap/FioriLaunchpad.html#WorkflowTask-displayInbox?Origin=ECDCLNET210%252CTS90000001&scenarioId=PAYMENT&showAdditionalAttributes=true&/replaceDetail/ECDCLNET210/000004868684/TaskCollection(SAP__Origin='ECDCLNET210',InstanceID='000004868684')

When trying to do Back in the following ways, it throws me out on the LaunchPad:

```
window.history.go(-1)
```

or

```
sap.ushell.Container.getService("CrossApplicationNavigation").backToPreviousApp("detail")
```

or

```
sap.ushell.Container.getService("CrossApplicationNavigation").historyBack();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
sap.ushell.Container.getService("CrossApplicationNavigation").
                toExternal({
                    target: { 
                        semanticObject : "WorkflowTask",
                        action: "displayInbox" }, 
                        params : { 
                            SAP__Origin : value1,
                            InstanceID : value2,
                            contextPath : value3
                        }
                     }
                );
```